# How to identify the amount of neurons and layers in a Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm watching this lecture on youtube about neural networks. I'm unsure on how to identify the amount of neurons and layers in the network. I have posted the lecture slide from the youtube lecture on the left with 3 neurons and 2 layers. I found an image on google and posted it on the right. Are my guesses for the number neurons and layers correct for the google image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amount of neurons and layers are correct in your left (from lecture) image and on the second one you are wrong. There is **three layers** and **twelve neurons**, but whole number of neurons doesn't have any meaning, most important is how many neurons are in each layer. So you can describe this network like this:

> Neural Network with three layers, first layer (input layer) consists
>   with **four neurons**, second layer (hidden layer) - with **six
>   neurons** and third layer (output layer) - with **two neurons**.

Even in this picture you have layers marked and well represented graphically

[image]

In any networks you have *input layer* and *output layer*, so you already have two layers and if inputs are being processed by another neurons before output neurons, it means that you have hidden layer. You can have many hidden layers in your net, it is called **multi-layered neural net**. Here is a examples some of them:

*this is **four layered** neural network with **two hidden layers***
[image]

*this is more complex network with **three hidden layers**. (**Five layers in sum**)*
[image]

**NOTE:**

> Increasing of layers in your network increases it's training time

Comment: An observation: the lecture is wrong. There is an implied input layer to the left that is not being called out. Assuming the convention that we do not count the input layer in the number of layers, then all of the examples you gave (and the OP's example) would have one fewer layer than mentioned.

Comment: it is just case of agreement. Someone considers inputs as layers and someone - not. To be honest, I agree with you, I dont consider inputs as layers because there is not any activation functions. But in the question there was an example from lecture where undelined that this 'perceptron'  is two layered. So I tried to explain according to question but not according to my consideration